# UITextField Apple's Edit Effect

Tags: ios, uitextfield

How can I reproduce Apple's blue fading border effect when UITextField is in editing mode

Comment: By writing the same code Apple used for it.

Comment: I had the same thought but unfortunately it became impossible to find it.